# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0

Tags: android, github, gradle

I want to use [MusicBobber](https://github.com/Cleveroad/MusicBobber) library in my project, but this error showed up

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
```

I have `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1`
and this is complete `gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tabaneshahr.playaudiotest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

    compile 'com.cleveroad:audiowidget:0.9.2'
}
```

I'd searched stackoverflow but noting useful. what should I do? does `minSDK` must change? shall I download anything?

Comment: Use proxy to sync your project and issue will be fixed.

Comment: I've tried proxy, error still remains @Amir

Comment: Are you sure proxy correctly set? if you can fetch SDK update it's means that your proxy set otherwise it's not.

Comment: Also it doesnt related to Min-SDK at all. appCompat is support api from 7 and above.

Comment: Another thing to mention: replace 23.1.1 to 23.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First,** replace your `appcompat` compile line with the latest one like this:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
```

Update to the `targetSdkVersion 24` as well.

and remove the compile line for the library:

```
    compile 'com.cleveroad:audiowidget:0.9.2'
```

**Second,** clean/build and run the project, you should not get any errors. If this happened, then your problem is not with the `appcompact` at all, but it is with the library.

**Thrid,** try to add the library compile line and again and let the `gradle` sync. If you still getting a problem, then I recommend to save your self the hassle and integerate the library in your code manually by doing the following this [link](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-studio-add-library-project/) steps

Hope it helps!

Comment: for replacing `appcompat` `compileSdkVersion 24` is needed, but mine is `23`. shall I download `API 24`?

Answer (score 1):

Please update your build tool version :

```
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

to 25 or you can use

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

Clean and rebuild your android project.

Answer (score 0):

```
> create a new project and you will see exact version .
```

for example for me in project file was :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
```

but after created new project i saw it is like this :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
```

so changed and sync and fixed .

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error while trying to run [SQLite Android Bindings](https://sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/install.wiki). It still uses a very old gradle configuration (included below).

**TLDR**

[`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.4.0) is very old and only available on https://maven.google.com (`google()` in `build.gradle`) as of this writing. Make sure your root `build.gradle` includes the `google()` repository in its `allprojects.repositories` section:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

**`SQLite`'s woefully out of date `gradle` configuration**:

`$ROOT/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        // this was the problem. google() was missing!
    }
}
```

`$ROOT/sqlitetest/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
...
}
```